# Operations in free algebras are one to one.

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

Does anybody know a simple proof that operations in a free algebra of a certain type $\Omega$ have necessarily to be one to one? That is, in other words, a proof that a free $\Omega$-algebra is an $\Omega$-term algebra, without knowing about an explicit construction of an $\Omega$-term algebra itself.

Edit.
To be more precise, with free $\Omega$-algebra on a set $X$ I mean a free object in the category $\Omega$-Alg, as such defined by a universal factorization property, whereas an $\Omega$-term algebra $T$ on $X$ is defined by the properties that the inclusion of $X$ in the underlying set of $T$ and all the operations in $T$ are one to one and have disjoint images, and the image of $X$ in the underlying set of $T$ generates $T$.
It's easy to prove that the inclusion map $u: X \rightarrow |T|$ must be one to one, but I can't find a way to prove the same for any operation $s_T$ where $s\in\Omega$.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using an explicit construction of the term algebra?  That is typically how you prove concrete facts about objects defined using universal properties: by explicitly constructing what they look like (or at least, some explicit structure that they map to using the universal property).

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Of course one can produce an $\Omega$-term algebra, show that it is a free $\Omega$-algebra, and verify that in it all the operations are one to one, just because of how they have been defined. Incidentally, this is also a way to prove that a free $\Omega$-algebra exists. I am just trying to prove the point without doing this, it is surely possible.

Answer (score 2):

I take $\Omega$ to be the set of operation
symbols in the language, each symbol recognizing
its own arity.

The set of $\Omega$-terms over $X$ is
the smallest set $T_X$ of strings in the alphabet $X\cup \Omega$
satisfying the conditions that
(i) $X\subseteq T_X$ and (ii)
$$
t_1,\ldots,t_m\in T_X\Rightarrow f t_1\ldots t_m\in T_X
$$
for every $m$-ary operation symbol $f$ in $\Omega$, for every $m$.

The $\Omega$-term algebra $\mathbb T_X$
over $X$ is the algebra with universe
$T_X$ where, for each $m$, and each $m$-ary operation
symbol $f$, $f^{\mathbb T_X}$ is the operation
$f^{\mathbb T_X}(t_1,\ldots,t_m) = f t_1\ldots t_m$.

The algebra $\mathbb T_X$ satisfies
(i) the universal mapping
property over $X$ with respect to the class of $\Omega$-algebras, and
(ii) the operations of $\mathbb T_X$ are 1-1.
These items are proved using induction and
the unique readability
of terms. (That is,
$f t_1,\ldots,t_m = g u_1, \ldots, u_n$ implies
these strings are identical: $m=n, f=g, t_i=u_i$ for all $i$.)
Since the free $\Omega$-algebra over $X$ is unique
up to isomorphism, and $\mathbb T_X$ is
free over $X$ and has injective operations,
any free $\Omega$-algebra over $X$ must have injective operations.

Comment: This is absolutely correct, and it corresponds to what I wrote in a comment answering to @Eric Wofsey, in that it uses an explicit construction of an $\Omega$-term algebra. What I would like to do is to prove that a free $\Omega$-algebra on a set $X$, defined by means of the universal factorisation property, is an $\Omega$-term algebra on $X$, defined as a pair $(T,u)$, where $T$ is an $\Omega$-algebra and $u:X\rightarrow |T|$, such that: 1) $u$ and all the operations $s_T$ are one to one 2) the images of $u$ and of all the operations $s_T$ are disjoint 3) the image of $u$ generates $T$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is a $n$-ary operation of the relevant type.
If
$$f(x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}, x_i, x_{i+1}, \ldots, x_n) = f(x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}, y, x_{i+1}, \ldots, x_n),$$
where $y$ is something other than $x_i$, then the above equality is a non-trivial identity of the algebra, which is then not free.

(I am supposing that by a free algebra of a certain type you mean the term algebra without any identities, aka, the completely free algebra. If you mean the free algebra on any variety, then that is just not true.)

Comment: With free $\Omega$-algebra I surely don't mean an $\Omega$-term algebra, indeed what I ask to prove is exactly the fact that the former must needs have the properties of the latter. With free $\Omega$-algebra I mean the $\Omega$-algebra defined as a free object in the category $\Omega$-Alg.

Comment: @alex I don't know if these objects are the same or not. You used the universal algebra tag, and not the category theory and now you claim that the relevant notion to you is the one from category theory? Any way, I suspect they are the same.

Comment: For me universal algebra lives in the context of category theory, but I can add the category tag. Of course they are the same, but one has to prove that, as they are defined in two completely different ways. This is exactly the point.

Comment: @Alex then I suppose you made the wrong question. What kind of answer would you expect? One using the Universal Mapping Property? When there are different equivalent ways to define something and one is trying to prove they are, indeed, equivalent, it's better start by stating clearly what is the starting point and the goal. If I were you, I would perhaps make another post, since you already have an answer to this one, so it wouldn't be nice to edit your post in a way that this answer would no longer be an answer to your edited post. Best wishes anyway!

Comment: I already edited the post, clarifying that I did so, and so making also clear that your answer was a perfectly adequate one to the post in its original form, owing to my not having stated the question clearly enough.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $F$ is a free $\Omega$-algebra on $X$ with $i:X\to F$ the inclusion.  Let $F_n$ denote the subset of elements of $F$ that can be obtained by starting with the image of $i$ and then applying operations of $\Omega$ at most $n$ times.  I claim first that $F=\bigcup_n F_n$.  Indeed, note that $\bigcup F_n$ is a subalgebra of $F$ which contains the image of $i$, and thus also has the universal property of a free algebra on $X$ (the uniqueness being satisfied since the image of $i$ generates $\bigcup F_n$).  By Yoneda, it follows that the inclusion map $\bigcup F_n\to F$ must be an isomorphism.

Now let us prove every operation of $\Omega$ is injective on $F$.  Let $s$ be an $m$-ary operation of $\Omega$ and $x,y\in F^m$ be distinct tuples; we wish to show $s(x)\neq s(y)$.  Let $n$ be minimal such that $x,y\in F_n^m$; we may assume without loss of generality that some entry of $x$ is in $F_n\setminus F_{n-1}$.  Note also that since we assume $x\neq y$, $F$ must have at least two elements.  Now let $F'$ be the algebra with the same underlying set as $F$ and the same algebra structure except that we redefine the value of $s(x)$ in $F'$ to be some element different from $s(y)$ (such an element exists since $F$ has at least two elements).  By the universal property of $F$, there is a homomorphism $\varphi:F\to F'$ that is the identity on the image of $i$.  Note also that all the operations of $F$ and $F'$ are the same when restricted to $F_{n-1}$, since $x$ has an entry in $F_n\setminus F_{n-1}$.  It follows that $\varphi$ is the identity when restricted to $F_n$ (since every element of $F_n$ is obtained by starting with the image of $i$ and repeatedly applying operations, where in each step the inputs to the operations are all in $F_{n-1}$).  In particular, $\varphi(x)=x$ and $\varphi(y)=y$, so since $s(x)$ and $s(y)$ are different in $F'$ they must be different in $F$ as well.

Comment: I like this, only, I might be wrong, but it seems to me that you don't really use the inductive hypothesis, you just need the least $n$ such that $x$ and $y$ have all entries in $F_n$, which ensures that the operations are the same in $F_{n-1}$.

Comment: Oh, you're right!